Statistical Rethinking - Paired data analysis
I would like to expand the model on the "6.2 Post-treatment bias" example from book Statistical Rethinking (pp170, 2nd edition) to account for different operators.
It's a case of paired data (pre/post treatment - $y_0/y_1$) which is based on the idea that the ratio between the before/after treatment in $p = \frac{y_1}{y_0}$. So, instead of doing a paired t-test (getting the difference $y_0 - y_1$) is doing the analysis presented here by  Solomon Kurz
$$\begin{align*}
h_{1i} & \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_i, \sigma) \\
\mu_i  & = h_{0i} \times p \\
p      & \sim \operatorname{Log-Normal}(0, 0.25) \\
\sigma & \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1).
\end{align*}$$
Now, assuming that  $y_0 \& y_1$ are measured by different operators (or equipment, etc) I would like to quantify this error with a model  $y \sim 1 (1|operator) $
The major assumption is that the operators in pre-treatment are't trained so I would like to quantify the operator effect separately, i.e. $y_0 \sim 1 (1|operator) $ and $y_1 \sim 1 (1|operator)$
The approach that I have thought is below. The two different models are connected by the ratio $p$ which should be somewhere around 1 (and for sure above 0)
$$
\mu_0 = 1 + (1|operator) \\
\mu_1 = 1 + (1|operator) \\
p\sim LogN(\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_0}, \sigma)\\
y_0 \sim N(\mu_0, \sigma_0) \\
y_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1) \\
$$
But does it make sense? How would it be better to expand the model from Statistical Rethinking and quantify separately the operator's effect in pre/post treatment?
(*By turning the data into a long format a multilevel model could do the job. But as a multilevel model should have the (1|subject) term (to account about the paired data-subjects) this increases the number of parameters. Instead the example 6.2 seems very elegant)
UPDATE
I thought to make a DAG and see where it will take me.
For now I have it as a latent variable model which looks like that,
$$
\mu_0 = 1 + y_L + (1|operator) \\
\mu_1 = 1 + y_L + (1|operator) \\
y_L \sim N(\mu_L, \sigma_L) \\
y_0 \sim N(\mu_0, \sigma_0) \\
y_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1) \\
$$
So, instead of looking to estimate the ratio $y_0 \& y_1$ (p) I have to estimate $y_L$ which is the difference (I hope).
The DAG should look like this

dag {
bb="0,0,1,1"
mu_0 [pos="0.464,0.365"]
mu_1 [pos="0.240,0.354"]
y0 [pos="0.462,0.465"]
y1 [adjusted,pos="0.243,0.467"]
y_L [pos="0.354,0.466"]
mu_0 -> y0
mu_1 -> y1
y_L -> y0
y_L -> y1
}

